# Ember (1.1) - A composite view of several routes at once

Tags: javascript, ember.js, single-page-application

Lets assume that I have two routes in an Ember application. These are totally separate routes names 'first' and 'second'. They have separate data models and different actions and so forth.

Everything is fine up to now.

How - we recognise that these parts of the application:

1. Are often used by the user together in an alternating fashion (do something in first, then in second then two things in first etc)
2. They take up little screen real-estate.

In a standard server side application, we would assume that we can create a new dashboard controller/view and somehow real in the other two controllers to handle all the things and diplay the results. The crucial thing is - **composition does not change the 'first' and 'second' controllers or views**.

I want to do the same thing, only in Ember. I've created [this JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1974/edit) to illustrate the problem.

I am aware of two existing solutions:

1. Use the existing models only (solution in the linked jsbin above) - the problem with this approach is obvious - the view are not used.
2. Use the [Component](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/) approach - I believe that this is not a good fit because these are not general, reusable components, and should be able to stand up on their own.

An ideal approach for me would be to use the `{{view}}` helper to somehow invoke the views but also pass in the controller data. (I've had a go at it in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1980/edit) but can't get seem to get it to work the the data from the controllers or properly setup a model for the route).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you will need to use the {{render}} helper

```
App.CompositeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return {
      first: this.modelFor('first'),
      second: this.modelFor('second')
    };
  }
});
```

in your handlebars template for the composite

```
{{render "first" model.first}}
{{render "second" model.second}}
```

Good luck

Comment: Hah! I've tried everything except `render` since I read somewhere that it can only be invoked "once per route". Anyway: If anyone is interested in the valid JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1981/edit

Comment: Had to revoke the "accepted answer" status. The above only works when you first visit the two 'single' controllers before going to the composites. Otherwise they render without data.

Comment: That's ok,I based the response in YOUR JSBin to illustrate the use of render, it's only an incomplete example, of course you will need to populate the model correctly, I can't guess if you are using ED, or whatever...

Comment: Yes, it's obvious now, but how do we actually populate the model without repetition? Do we need to move the model generation out of the routes? What is the best practice for this?

Comment: You can make a mixin with the apropiate functions to obtain first, second or all models, and then, use on the routes definitions and call the functions in the model hook of each route, you would have problems in the all function if you are returning promises, as an inspiration read this https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3006#issuecomment-21110139

Comment: Okay, but that's waaaay over engineered for what I had in mind. I'll probably stick to your answer as the best solution that is simple enought at this time, but I'm not 100% happy with the result :)